# C++ Method thread

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a thread for a method in a class. I have written this:

```
class Program
{
    public:
        Program();
        void render();
};

Program::Program()
{
    thread t(render);
}

void Program::render()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

Which gives me this error message:

"error C3867: 'Program::render': function call missing argument list; use '&Program::render' to create a pointer to member"

And when I write this instead:

```
thread t(&Program::render);
```

It says:

```
1>c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1149) : error C2064 : term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>          class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer - to - function or reference - to - function that takes appropriate number of arguments
1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Program::* )(void),void,Program,>,>::_Do_call<,>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Program::* )(void),void,Program,>,>::_Do_call<,>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<>)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Program::* )(void),void,Program,>,>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Program::* )(void),void,Program,>,>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled
1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(192) : while compiling class template member function 'unsigned int std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)'
1>          with
1>[
    1>              _Target = std::_Bind<true, void, std::_Pmf_wrap<void(__thiscall Program::*)(void), void, Program, >, >
        1>]
        1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(187) : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)' being compiled
        1>          with
        1>[
            1>              _Target = std::_Bind<true, void, std::_Pmf_wrap<void(__thiscall Program::*)(void), void, Program, >, >
                1>]
                1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(205) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>' being compiled
                1>          with
                1>[
                    1>              _Target = std::_Bind<true, void, std::_Pmf_wrap<void(__thiscall Program::*)(void), void, Program, >, >
                        1>]
                        1>          c:\program files(x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\thread(49) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Launch<std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Program::* )(void),void,Program,>,>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)' being compiled
                        1>          with
                        1>[
                            1>              _Target = std::_Bind<true, void, std::_Pmf_wrap<void(__thiscall Program::*)(void), void, Program, >, >
                                1>]
                                1>          c:\users\erik\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\c++gameengine\c++gameengine\program.cpp(16) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__thiscall Program::* )(void),>(_Fn &&)' being compiled
                                1>          with
                                1>[
                                    1>              _Fn = void(__thiscall Program::*)(void)
                                        1>]
```

I do not quite understand what is wrong. Could you explain and give me an solution to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`render` is a non-static member function, so it needs an object to call it on. You'll need to wrap it in a little function object to call it on the `Program`. There are two convenient ways to do that, according to taste:

```
thread t(&Program::render, this);
thread t([this]{render();});
```

The next problem is that the thread is local to the constructor, so is destroyed immediately. You mustn't destroy a thread object without joining it (waiting for the thread to complete) or detaching it. So either make it a member, so you can join it later; or detach it before returning.

Comment: Why do I have to join it? Shouldn't it stop when the function returns?

Comment: @ErikW: Because those are the rules. There's no way to stop a thread - it will run until it stops itself. It's an error (resulting in terminating the program) to destroy a joinable thread; you must either detach it, or keep hold of the thread object until you're ready to wait for it to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You should either make your class member function `static`, or use [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to pass the function to the `std::thread` instance.

Also note your `std::thread t;` variable is local to the constructor. You'll loose any connection to that thread this way and don't have anymore control over it after the constructor's scope ends.

Comment: No need for `bind`, there's a variadic constructor for that.

Comment: Or the variadic constructor `thread t(&Program::render, this)`, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Program::Program()
{
    std::thread t(&Program::render, this);
    t.join();
}
```

However, that achieves nothing, since it just blocks until the function call returns. Maybe you want to detach the thread?

```
std::thread(&Program::render, this).detach();
```

Now you need to build your own logic to tell the thread when it's time to stop.

Or you make the thread a class member:

```
struct Program
{
    void render();

    Program() : render_thread_(&Program::render, this) {}
    ~Program() { render_thread_.join(); }

    std::thread render_thread_;
};
```

Comment: In what case would you not want to detach() the thread? Threads does not seem useful if you don't call that function

Comment: @ErikW: Detaching almost never seems like a sane idea. You should be in control of your program's control flows and not randomly start forgetting about things. The final piece of code I wrote shows a stub example that executes concurrently without the need to detach.